# navigating between pages Windows phone runtime

Tags: memory-leaks, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Let say I have two pages Page1, and Page2.
When I launch the app, Page 1 is loading, then I can choose to go to Page2. Then I can go back in Page1.
The problem is, if I do Page1->Page2->Page1 several times the constructor of Page2 is called every time I navigate on it (I guess it's the same for Page1), and more and more memory is used. 
Besides, if the app is suspended and the resumed, the resuming method is called n-times the Page2 was instantiated.

So is there a way to avoid that please ?

Comment: What code are you currently using for navigation? When you "go back", you can use `GoBack` instead of `Navigate`. There's a `Backstack`, where `Navigat` pushes the new page to it and `GoBack` pops the last one, which is what you want.

Comment: I use GoBack from Page2 to Page1, so the constructor for Page1 is called only once, but to load Page2 from Page1 I use :  Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2)); and the constructor of Page2 is called each time => a new page is instantiated every time. Is there a way to check if Page2 is already instantiated and to load it instead of create a new one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Page.NavigationCacheMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode)

> By default, each navigation creates a new instance of the specific
>   Page subclass requested, and disposes the previous page instance. This
>   happens even when navigating back to a previously visited page or when
>   the new page type is the same as the previous page type. Apps that
>   involve frequent navigation to the same pages can cache and reuse the
>   page instances to make navigation more efficient. To do this, set the
>   CacheSize property to specify how many pages to cache. For each page
>   type that you want to cache, you must also set the
>   Page.NavigationCacheMode property to either Enabled or Required. Pages
>   with a Required cache mode are cached regardless of the CacheSize
>   value, and do not count against the CacheSize total.

Reference [Frame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame)

Comment: Are you sure that the previous page instance disposes ? Because when I'm monitoring the memory when I do loop Page1->Page2->Page1->Page2->... the memory is growing up.

Comment: Have you set NavigationCacheMode to Required on Page2?